# cmake execute_process() always fails with "No such file or directory" when I call git

Tags: cmake

On a linux machine, from a cmake project, I'm trying to call git using execute_process so that I can include info from source control into my app.

I created a little test to try and print the git version:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set (git_cmd "/usr/bin/git --version")
#set (git_cmd "ls") # returns success if you uncomment this line 
message(STATUS "git cmd: ${git_cmd}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${git_cmd}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

message(STATUS "git ver[${git_result}]: ${git_ver}")

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/versionInfo.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/versionInfo.h"
  )
```

Which gives the following output when you run make:

```
-- git cmd: /usr/bin/git --version
-- git ver[No such file or directory]: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rsanderson/build/githash:
```

But if I change the command to `ls` the result is valid and I see the dir listing print. I also checked with which that git is indeed in /usr/bin.

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

Comment: I get it to work removing the `--version`. Maybe this has to be a second argument.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments as a second option like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set (git_cmd "git")
set (git_arg "--version")
message(STATUS "git cmd: ${git_cmd}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${git_cmd} ${git_arg}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

message(STATUS "git ver[${git_result}]: ${git_ver}")
```

Comment: awesome.  That worked like a charm.  I was driving myself crazy the other day.

Comment: Nice... You deserve a bounty for this one.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above I'd also add the following:

OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE

```
find_package(Git QUIET)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} symbolic-ref --short HEAD
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE DISPLAY_GIT_BRANCH
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

On RedHat 8 with ninja installed I got parsing errors because of trailing whitespces