# cmake execute Python and excess python linked files

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmake

I am trying to convert an autotools script into cmake

The python file error.py reads an error_list.py and then creates an c-header file named error.h and saves it in the same source dir as error.py.

the following automake line: `errors.h: errors.py error_list.py $(PYTHON) errors.py --errors $@`

i changed to: 
`execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} errors.py  --errors error.h)`

when running cmake, error.py generates an read_error error_list.py

`exec (open ("error_list.py", 'r'),read())`

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: error_list.py`

if i run the command in a command window with the command: 
`python errors.py --errors error.h`
it work as expected.

Do i need to parse a rights command with the cmake expression? and how?

cheers

Comment: By default, *COMMAND* for `execute_process` is executed in the current **binary directory**. You may adjust directory for the command with *WORKING_DIRECTORY* option. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) for more details.

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797395/cmake-execute-process-always-fails-with-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-cal  this line did the trick: `execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/errors.py --errors ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/errors.h WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: Isn't just setting working direcory sufficient? Why do you need to make paths to the scripts and input file absolute, as them are already located in the *WORKING_DIRECTORY*?

Comment: Maybe it is, but set(WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) sets the global var WORKING_DIRECTORY to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}. in diffrent locations of the program this can mesh up stuff, because execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} errors.py --errors errors.h WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) passes the current source location as TYPE WORKING_DIRECTORY but doesn't actually sets the variable WORKING_DIRECTORY.  i double checked this :)

Comment: **Option** *WORKING_DIRECTORY* for `execute_process()` is not a **variable** *WORKING_DIRECTORY*. I meant `execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} errors.py --errors errors.h WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` which should also work for your case.

Comment: What is `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}`? It can only be the name of the Python executable. It cannot include other arguments. The CMake docs for [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) suck. They don't state how to use `execute_process` correctly, and they don't offer examples. Users have been suffering it since at least 2011 (cf., [cmake execute_process() always fails with “No such file or directory” when I call git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797395/608639)).